# ImportError: cannot import name '_NewEmptyTensorOp' from 'torchvision.ops.misc' in Python (version 3.10.9) in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: python, deep-learning, libraries, importerror, torchvision

I am trying to run a pre-trained neural network for object detection according to what is shown in the GitHub repository: [Deformable-DETR](https://github.com/fundamentalvision/Deformable-DETR), using this command in the terminal in Python (version 3.10.9) in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS:

```
./configs/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage.sh --resume ./pre-trained models/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage-checkpoint.pth --eval
```

I am following the same structure as it is shown in the repository:

```
<path to config file> --resume <path to pre-trained model> --eval
```

And I have downloaded the pre-trained neural network called: *Deformable DET ++ two-stage Deformable DETR*, and the validation set from COCO dataset (in the data folder), and followed the structure, as it is shown in the GitHub repository:

```
code_root/
└── data/
    └── coco/
        ├── train2017/
        ├── val2017/
        └── annotations/
            ├── instances_train2017.json
            └── instances_val2017.json
```

However, after I run the command in the terminal to make predictions from the pre-trained neural network, I get the following error message:

```
./configs/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage.sh --resume ./pre-trained models/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage-checkpoint.pth --eval
+ EXP_DIR=exps/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage
+ PY_ARGS='--resume ./pre-trained models/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage-checkpoint.pth --eval'
+ python -u main.py --output_dir exps/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage --with_box_refine --two_stage --resume ./pre-trained models/r50_deformable_detr_plus_iterative_bbox_refinement_plus_plus_two_stage-checkpoint.pth --eval
/home/tarsier/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: /home/tarsier/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/image.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5torch3jit17parseSchemaOrNameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
  warn(f"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tarsier/Documents/Walaris/Tasks/Task 2: Ground-based Object Detection/Code/Deformable-DETR/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    import datasets
  File "/home/tarsier/Documents/Walaris/Tasks/Task 2: Ground-based Object Detection/Code/Deformable-DETR/datasets/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .coco import build as build_coco
  File "/home/tarsier/Documents/Walaris/Tasks/Task 2: Ground-based Object Detection/Code/Deformable-DETR/datasets/coco.py", line 22, in <module>
    from util.misc import get_local_rank, get_local_size
  File "/home/tarsier/Documents/Walaris/Tasks/Task 2: Ground-based Object Detection/Code/Deformable-DETR/util/misc.py", line 32, in <module>
    from torchvision.ops.misc import _NewEmptyTensorOp
ImportError: cannot import name '_NewEmptyTensorOp' from 'torchvision.ops.misc' (/home/tarsier/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/ops/misc.py)
```

It seems that the error message suggests that there is an import error in the code. Specifically, it seems that the module *torchvision.ops.misc* is unable to import the *_NewEmptyTensorOp class*.

This issue could be caused by a version incompatibility between the *torchvision* library and other dependencies in your environment.

I run the command `conda list torch` to check the versions from *torch* and *torchvision*, and this is the result:

```
# packages in environment at /home/tarsier/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
torch                     2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
```

And this is a list of the all the packages and the corresponding version installed in my computer by running the command `pip list`:

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------------
alabaster                     0.7.12
anaconda-client               1.11.2
anaconda-navigator            2.4.0
anaconda-project              0.11.1
anyio                         3.5.0
appdirs                       1.4.4
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arrow                         1.2.3
astroid                       2.14.2
astropy                       5.1
asttokens                     2.0.5
atomicwrites                  1.4.0
attrs                         22.1.0
Automat                       20.2.0
autopep8                      1.6.0
Babel                         2.11.0
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.4
backports.tempfile            1.0
backports.weakref             1.0.post1
bcrypt                        3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.1
binaryornot                   0.4.4
black                         22.6.0
bleach                        4.1.0
bokeh                         2.4.3
boltons                       23.0.0
Bottleneck                    1.3.5
brotlipy                      0.7.0
certifi                       2023.5.7
cffi                          1.15.1
chardet                       4.0.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.4
click                         8.0.4
cloudpickle                   2.0.0
clyent                        1.2.2
cmake                         3.26.3
colorama                      0.4.6
colorcet                      3.0.1
comm                          0.1.2
conda                         23.3.1
conda-build                   3.24.0
conda-content-trust           0.1.3
conda-pack                    0.6.0
conda-package-handling        2.0.2
conda_package_streaming       0.7.0
conda-repo-cli                1.0.41
conda-token                   0.4.0
conda-verify                  3.4.2
constantly                    15.1.0
contourpy                     1.0.5
cookiecutter                  1.7.3
cryptography                  39.0.1
cssselect                     1.1.0
cycler                        0.11.0
Cython                        0.29.34
cytoolz                       0.12.0
daal4py                       2023.0.2
dask                          2022.7.0
datashader                    0.14.4
datashape                     0.5.4
debugpy                       1.5.1
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
diff-match-patch              20200713
dill                          0.3.6
distributed                   2022.7.0
docstring-to-markdown         0.11
docutils                      0.18.1
entrypoints                   0.4
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
executing                     0.8.3
fastjsonschema                2.16.2
filelock                      3.9.0
flake8                        6.0.0
Flask                         2.2.2
flit_core                     3.6.0
fonttools                     4.25.0
fsspec                        2022.11.0
fst-pso                       1.8.1
future                        0.18.3
FuzzyTM                       2.0.5
gensim                        4.3.1
glob2                         0.7
gmpy2                         2.1.2
greenlet                      2.0.1
h5py                          3.7.0
HeapDict                      1.0.1
holoviews                     1.15.4
huggingface-hub               0.10.1
hvplot                        0.8.2
hyperlink                     21.0.0
idna                          3.4
imagecodecs                   2021.8.26
imageio                       2.26.0
imagesize                     1.4.1
imbalanced-learn              0.10.1
importlib-metadata            4.11.3
incremental                   21.3.0
inflection                    0.5.1
iniconfig                     1.1.1
intake                        0.6.7
intervaltree                  3.1.0
ipykernel                     6.19.2
ipython                       8.10.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipywidgets                    7.6.5
isort                         5.9.3
itemadapter                   0.3.0
itemloaders                   1.0.4
itsdangerous                  2.0.1
jedi                          0.18.1
jeepney                       0.7.1
jellyfish                     0.9.0
Jinja2                        3.1.2
jinja2-time                   0.2.0
jmespath                      0.10.0
joblib                        1.1.1
json5                         0.9.6
jsonpatch                     1.32
jsonpointer                   2.1
jsonschema                    4.17.3
jupyter                       1.0.0
jupyter_client                7.3.4
jupyter-console               6.6.2
jupyter_core                  5.2.0
jupyter-server                1.23.4
jupyterlab                    3.5.3
jupyterlab-pygments           0.1.2
jupyterlab_server             2.19.0
jupyterlab-widgets            1.0.0
keyring                       23.4.0
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
lazy-object-proxy             1.6.0
libarchive-c                  2.9
lit                           16.0.3
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        1.0.0
lxml                          4.9.1
lz4                           3.1.3
Markdown                      3.4.1
MarkupSafe                    2.1.1
matplotlib                    3.7.0
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mccabe                        0.7.0
miniful                       0.0.6
mistune                       0.8.4
mkl-fft                       1.3.1
mkl-random                    1.2.2
mkl-service                   2.4.0
mock                          4.0.3
mpmath                        1.2.1
msgpack                       1.0.3
multipledispatch              0.6.0
munkres                       1.1.4
mypy-extensions               0.4.3
navigator-updater             0.3.0
nbclassic                     0.5.2
nbclient                      0.5.13
nbconvert                     6.5.4
nbformat                      5.7.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
networkx                      2.8.4
nltk                          3.7
notebook                      6.5.2
notebook_shim                 0.2.2
numba                         0.56.4
numexpr                       2.8.4
numpy                         1.23.5
numpydoc                      1.5.0
nvidia-cublas-cu11            11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11        11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11        11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11      11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11             8.5.0.96
nvidia-cufft-cu11             10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11            10.2.10.91
nvidia-cusolver-cu11          11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusparse-cu11          11.7.4.91
nvidia-nccl-cu11              2.14.3
nvidia-nvtx-cu11              11.7.91
openpyxl                      3.0.10
packaging                     22.0
pandas                        1.5.3
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
panel                         0.14.3
param                         1.12.3
parsel                        1.6.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.2.0
pathlib                       1.0.1
pathspec                      0.10.3
patsy                         0.5.3
pep8                          1.7.1
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.4.0
pip                           22.3.1
pkginfo                       1.9.6
platformdirs                  2.5.2
plotly                        5.9.0
pluggy                        1.0.0
ply                           3.11
pooch                         1.4.0
poyo                          0.5.0
prometheus-client             0.14.1
prompt-toolkit                3.0.36
Protego                       0.1.16
psutil                        5.9.0
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
py                            1.11.0
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                0.2.8
pycocotools                   2.0.6
pycodestyle                   2.10.0
pycosat                       0.6.4
pycparser                     2.21
pyct                          0.5.0
pycurl                        7.45.1
PyDispatcher                  2.0.5
pydocstyle                    6.3.0
pyerfa                        2.0.0
pyflakes                      3.0.1
pyFUME                        0.2.25
Pygments                      2.11.2
PyHamcrest                    2.0.2
PyJWT                         2.4.0
pylint                        2.16.2
pylint-venv                   2.3.0
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0
pyodbc                        4.0.34
pyOpenSSL                     23.0.0
pyparsing                     3.0.9
PyQt5-sip                     12.11.0
pyrsistent                    0.18.0
PySocks                       1.7.1
pytest                        7.1.2
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-lsp-black              1.2.1
python-lsp-jsonrpc            1.0.0
python-lsp-server             1.7.1
python-slugify                5.0.2
python-snappy                 0.6.1
pytoolconfig                  1.2.5
pytz                          2022.7
pyviz-comms                   2.0.2
PyWavelets                    1.4.1
pyxdg                         0.27
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         23.2.0
QDarkStyle                    3.0.2
qstylizer                     0.2.2
QtAwesome                     1.2.2
qtconsole                     5.4.0
QtPy                          2.2.0
queuelib                      1.5.0
regex                         2022.7.9
requests                      2.28.1
requests-file                 1.5.1
requests-toolbelt             0.9.1
rope                          1.7.0
Rtree                         1.0.1
ruamel.yaml                   0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib              0.2.6
ruamel-yaml-conda             0.17.21
scikit-image                  0.19.3
scikit-learn                  1.2.1
scikit-learn-intelex          20230228.214242
scipy                         1.10.1
Scrapy                        2.8.0
seaborn                       0.12.2
SecretStorage                 3.3.1
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
service-identity              18.1.0
setuptools                    65.6.3
simpful                       2.11.0
sip                           6.6.2
six                           1.16.0
smart-open                    5.2.1
sniffio                       1.2.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1
Sphinx                        5.0.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
spyder                        5.4.1
spyder-kernels                2.4.1
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.39
stack-data                    0.2.0
statsmodels                   0.13.5
sympy                         1.11.1
tables                        3.7.0
tabulate                      0.8.10
TBB                           0.2
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.0.1
terminado                     0.17.1
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.2.1
threadpoolctl                 2.2.0
three-merge                   0.1.1
tifffile                      2021.7.2
tinycss2                      1.2.1
tldextract                    3.2.0
tokenizers                    0.11.4
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
tomlkit                       0.11.1
toolz                         0.12.0
torch                         2.0.1
torchvision                   0.15.2
tornado                       6.1
tqdm                          4.65.0
traitlets                     5.7.1
transformers                  4.24.0
triton                        2.0.0
Twisted                       22.2.0
typing_extensions             4.4.0
ujson                         5.4.0
Unidecode                     1.2.0
urllib3                       1.26.14
w3lib                         1.21.0
watchdog                      2.1.6
wcwidth                       0.2.5
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              0.58.0
Werkzeug                      2.2.2
whatthepatch                  1.0.2
wheel                         0.38.4
widgetsnbextension            3.5.2
wrapt                         1.14.1
wurlitzer                     3.0.2
xarray                        2022.11.0
yapf                          0.31.0
zict                          2.1.0
zipp                          3.11.0
zope.interface                5.4.0
zstandard                     0.19.0
```

I tried to check if I have the latest version of *torch* and *torchvision* installed by running this command: `pip install torch torchvision --upgrade`. However, it still has the same error.

I tried to downgrade the *torchvision* version to the version 0.13.2. However, I had errors in importing the datasets from *torchvision* in *coco.py* from the GitHub repository:

`from .torchvision_datasets import CocoDetection as TvCocoDetection`

This is the *coco.py* code:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Deformable DETR
# Copyright (c) 2020 SenseTime. All Rights Reserved.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 [see LICENSE for details]
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Modified from DETR (https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr)
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. All Rights Reserved
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

"""
COCO dataset which returns image_id for evaluation.
Mostly copy-paste from https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/13b35ff/references/detection/coco_utils.py
"""
from pathlib import Path

import torch
import torch.utils.data
from pycocotools import mask as coco_mask

from .torchvision_datasets import CocoDetection as TvCocoDetection
from util.misc import get_local_rank, get_local_size
import datasets.transforms as T


class CocoDetection(TvCocoDetection):
    def __init__(self, img_folder, ann_file, transforms, return_masks, cache_mode=False, local_rank=0, local_size=1):
        super(CocoDetection, self).__init__(img_folder, ann_file,
                                            cache_mode=cache_mode, local_rank=local_rank, local_size=local_size)
        self._transforms = transforms
        self.prepare = ConvertCocoPolysToMask(return_masks)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img, target = super(CocoDetection, self).__getitem__(idx)
        image_id = self.ids[idx]
        target = {'image_id': image_id, 'annotations': target}
        img, target = self.prepare(img, target)
        if self._transforms is not None:
            img, target = self._transforms(img, target)
        return img, target


def convert_coco_poly_to_mask(segmentations, height, width):
    masks = []
    for polygons in segmentations:
        rles = coco_mask.frPyObjects(polygons, height, width)
        mask = coco_mask.decode(rles)
        if len(mask.shape) < 3:
            mask = mask[..., None]
        mask = torch.as_tensor(mask, dtype=torch.uint8)
        mask = mask.any(dim=2)
        masks.append(mask)
    if masks:
        masks = torch.stack(masks, dim=0)
    else:
        masks = torch.zeros((0, height, width), dtype=torch.uint8)
    return masks


class ConvertCocoPolysToMask(object):
    def __init__(self, return_masks=False):
        self.return_masks = return_masks

    def __call__(self, image, target):
        w, h = image.size

        image_id = target["image_id"]
        image_id = torch.tensor([image_id])

        anno = target["annotations"]

        anno = [obj for obj in anno if 'iscrowd' not in obj or obj['iscrowd'] == 0]

        boxes = [obj["bbox"] for obj in anno]
        # guard against no boxes via resizing
        boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(-1, 4)
        boxes[:, 2:] += boxes[:, :2]
        boxes[:, 0::2].clamp_(min=0, max=w)
        boxes[:, 1::2].clamp_(min=0, max=h)

        classes = [obj["category_id"] for obj in anno]
        classes = torch.tensor(classes, dtype=torch.int64)

        if self.return_masks:
            segmentations = [obj["segmentation"] for obj in anno]
            masks = convert_coco_poly_to_mask(segmentations, h, w)

        keypoints = None
        if anno and "keypoints" in anno[0]:
            keypoints = [obj["keypoints"] for obj in anno]
            keypoints = torch.as_tensor(keypoints, dtype=torch.float32)
            num_keypoints = keypoints.shape[0]
            if num_keypoints:
                keypoints = keypoints.view(num_keypoints, -1, 3)

        keep = (boxes[:, 3] > boxes[:, 1]) & (boxes[:, 2] > boxes[:, 0])
        boxes = boxes[keep]
        classes = classes[keep]
        if self.return_masks:
            masks = masks[keep]
        if keypoints is not None:
            keypoints = keypoints[keep]

        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = classes
        if self.return_masks:
            target["masks"] = masks
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        if keypoints is not None:
            target["keypoints"] = keypoints

        # for conversion to coco api
        area = torch.tensor([obj["area"] for obj in anno])
        iscrowd = torch.tensor([obj["iscrowd"] if "iscrowd" in obj else 0 for obj in anno])
        target["area"] = area[keep]
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd[keep]

        target["orig_size"] = torch.as_tensor([int(h), int(w)])
        target["size"] = torch.as_tensor([int(h), int(w)])

        return image, target


def make_coco_transforms(image_set):

    normalize = T.Compose([
        T.ToTensor(),
        T.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

    scales = [480, 512, 544, 576, 608, 640, 672, 704, 736, 768, 800]

    if image_set == 'train':
        return T.Compose([
            T.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            T.RandomSelect(
                T.RandomResize(scales, max_size=1333),
                T.Compose([
                    T.RandomResize([400, 500, 600]),
                    T.RandomSizeCrop(384, 600),
                    T.RandomResize(scales, max_size=1333),
                ])
            ),
            normalize,
        ])

    if image_set == 'val':
        return T.Compose([
            T.RandomResize([800], max_size=1333),
            normalize,
        ])

    raise ValueError(f'unknown {image_set}')


def build(image_set, args):
    root = Path(args.coco_path)
    assert root.exists(), f'provided COCO path {root} does not exist'
    mode = 'instances'
    PATHS = {
        "train": (root / "train2017", root / "annotations" / f'{mode}_train2017.json'),
        "val": (root / "val2017", root / "annotations" / f'{mode}_val2017.json'),
    }

    img_folder, ann_file = PATHS[image_set]
    dataset = CocoDetection(img_folder, ann_file, transforms=make_coco_transforms(image_set), return_masks=args.masks,
                            cache_mode=args.cache_mode, local_rank=get_local_rank(), local_size=get_local_size())
    return dataset
```

Comment: I solved it: I created a conda environment: `conda create -n deformable_detr python=3.7 pip` and activate it: `conda activate deformable_detr`. And then, I run the command to install torch and torchvision older versions: `pip install torch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 -qq` and run the command to install the requirements: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The problems in util.misc.py are on lines 30 and 56, e.g.

```
if float(torchvision.__version__[:3]) < 0.5:
```

The major and minor parts of the semantic versioning for your installed `torchvision` package are examined in a way that looks at a fixed number of 3 chars. That works fine for a version such as '0.6.0'. However, this approach breaks down when the minor has two digits, e.g. version '0.16.0' because the first three chars gives 0.1 which appears to be less than version 0.5.

There are several options for comparing semantic versions such as LooseVersion and StrictVersion (from setuptools.distutils) but I personally went with Version from packaging by adding this import near the top of the file:

```
from packaging.version import Version
```

then change the condition statements (approx. lines 30 & 56) to:

```
if Version(torchvision.__version__) < Version('0.5.0'):
    ...

elif Version(torchvision.__version__) < Version('0.7.0'):
    ...
```

You may need to add `packaging` to your requirements.txt, depending on your python version and how you manage your python environment.

An alternative to this solution is to roll back `torch` and `torchvision` versions such that `torchvision<0.10.0`, However, that may require an older version of CUDA.

I have successfully trained a Deformable-DETR model on an RTX3090 with 535.146.02 Nvidia drivers installed, plus the following python and pypi-sourced libs | versions:

```
Python                        3.11.6
torch                         2.1.2
torchvision                   0.16.2
```

which installs a number of nvidia CUDA12-based dependencies (e.g. nvidia-cublas-cu12 v12.1.3.1).

The advantage of this solution proposed here is enabling CUDA12 and all of the advantages it has over CUDA11 (think faster: 'PyTorch 2.x: faster, more pythonic and as dynamic as ever' according to the pytorch.org).

`Version()` plays well with pre/post/other suffixes too, for example '+cu121'. Test it if you like with some lines:

```
from packaging.version import Version

assert Version("0.4.0+cu121") < Version("0.7.0")
```